# youtube-dl : how to skip downloads lower than 480p resolution?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, video, youtube-dl

When using the popular program youtube-dl, how can I skip download of certain videos, particularly ones that have a lower quality than 480p resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `youtube-dl` [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection-examples) examples:

`youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height>=480]'`

Will discriminate against videos that don't at least equal 480p.